# Changing card style when clicked

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-router, styled-components

I am mapping data into a card, onClick of the card, it shows that it is active by background color change and input box being checked. This is my code.
I am mapping data into a card, so i am rendering a list of card.  onClick of the card, it shows that it is active by change in background color and input box being checked.it is checked when i click it but when it navigates to a new route per id, it is unchecked. This is code of the card component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function Card(props) {
  const {item,id} = props;

  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [background, setBackground] = useState("#F3F1FA");
  const [cardBorder, setCardBorder] = useState("transparent");
  const history = useHistory();

  const CheckBox = () => { 
    setChecked(!checked);
    if (checked === true) {
      setBackground("#F3F1FA");
      setCardBorder("transparent");
    } else {
      setBackground("#fff");
      setCardBorder("2px solid #7f67ce");
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <CardWrapper
      onClick={()=>{
      CheckBox();
      // console.log(props.id)
      history.push(`/invoice/${id}`) 
    }}
      background={background}
      cardBorder={cardBorder}
    >
     <div> Content </div>
      <Check>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          value={checked}
          onChange={() => CheckBox}
        />
      </Check>
    </CardWrapper>
  );
}

const CardWrapper = styled.button`
  background-color: ${(props) => props.background};
  border: ${(props) => props.cardBorder};
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 347px;
  height: 129px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  color: #7f67ce;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  img {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
  @media(max-width:1200px){
    width:300px;
  }
  @media(max-width:1200px){
    width:280px;
  }
  :first-child{
    margin-top:0px;
  }

`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here instead of `setChecked(!checked);` use setState with arrow function (and everywhere where next state depends on old state) `setChecked((prevValue) => !prevValue)`.
And here  `onChange={() => CheckBox}` you need to call the actual function inside the arrow function like:  `onChange={() => CheckBox()}` or give it's reference  `onChange={CheckBox}`

Comment: Thanks for the response, it still doesnt work.
i added an additional code, ony the first card is checked and it doesnt change with a new card clicked.
const value= id ? false : true
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(value);

Answer (score 0):

You want your data to be persistent across app so you need to use one of:

- React Context API
- Redux
- Save to local storage / session storage and then on useEffect, first render to initialize your data with the saved one